# getText() of an array of TextView initialized in .xml

Tags: android, textview, nullpointerexception, gettext

I have defined the TextView array as final.
And I set a OnClickListener() for all the array elements,
and I am able to use setBackground (even the array is not set as final).
But I cannot use getText() method which return NullPointerException during operation.

Do you guys know why is the problem existed?

```
final ArrayList<TextView> seats = new ArrayList<TextView>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.A1));
    seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.A2));
    seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.A3));
    .
    .
    for (int i = 0; i<seats.size(); i++)
        seats.get(i).setOnClickListener(seatClick);
    .
    .
}
OnClickListener seatClick = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        v.setBackgroundColor(-16711681);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
};
```

The TextView is defined something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/A1"
        android:background="#0AFC1A"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested your code its working fine. just change it.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this is full code

```
seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2));
            seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3));
            seats.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4));



            OnClickListener seatClick = new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                  v.setBackgroundColor(-16711681);
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i<seats.size(); i++)
                seats.get(i).setOnClickListener(seatClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement `v.setBackgroundColor(-16711681);` runs successfully as said by you so your `v` object is perfect and not `null`. I guess your getText method here `((TextView)v).getText()` returns `null` and so the call of `toString()` on `null` results in NPE. You should check for it.

Comment: @henry You should tweak for it that why does it returns null.

Comment: sorry but i would like to ask how to tweak for it?

Comment: @Henry I'm not an android expert so can't tell you perfect solution, what you can try is, See if View you are getting in onClick is the correct one? Is text view has any text associated with it?

Comment: i have text defined for the textfield and the application can display them on the screen..see the update on the question above..just dun know why the getText() returns null...i have no ideas for a long time so i posted it here